# Does scala 3 have true type alias? How to implement it?

Tags: scala, scala-3, type-alias

In many Scala tutorials & marketing materials, I found many people abusing terminology by mingling "type alias" and "dependent type", while in reality they are not the same thing.

E.g. in the following example, `TakeAlias` is a dependent type, not a type alias. As a result, it will cause compilation to fail:

```scala
object TrueTypeAlias {

  trait Unaliased[+T] {

    def take1: List[Seq[(T, T)]]

    def take2: List[Seq[(T, T)]]

    def take3: List[Seq[(T, T)]]
  }

  trait Aliased[+T] {

    type TakeAlias = List[Seq[(T, T)]]

    def take1: TakeAlias

    def take2: TakeAlias

    def take3: TakeAlias
  }
}

/*
TrueTypeAlias.scala:16:10: covariant type T occurs in invariant position in type  = List[Seq[(T, T)]] of type TakeAlias
one error found
*/
```

The problem is: what does it take to implement true type alias? Is there a compiler mechanism/extension I can use to make it work?

Comment: That is both a type alias and patch-dependant type, and neither are related to the compilation error. - To just create a type alias you just use the `type` keyword in an object or at the top level _(only **Scala 3**)_

Comment: Your `TakeAlias` is a `type-alias member` of trait `Aliased` which is actually a `type-alias` for `type` `List[Seq[(T, T)]]`. This is same as having in `Int value member` named `i` having a value `10`. And since this `type-alias` is a member of the `trait`... the type refered by this `type-alias` is also a `path dependent type` as it can not exist and can not be refered to without first having the reference of the `trait instance`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`type TakeAlias = List[Seq[(T, T)]]` is a type alias in the sense that `TakeAlias` can be used instead of `List[Seq[(T, T)]]`.

At the same time `type TakeAlias = ...` is a type member of the trait. So `x.TakeAlias` (for `x: Aliased[T]`) is a path-dependent type. Although this path dependency is now trivial: `x.TakeAlias` are the same for different `x: Aliased[T]` with the same `T`, namely all `x.TakeAlias` are `List[Seq[(T, T)]]`. And since `type TakeAlias = ...` is a type member, all variance-position restrictions are applied.

I'd fix this code making type alias generic

```
trait Aliased[+T] {

  type TakeAlias[+S] = List[Seq[(S, S)]]
  //type TakeAlias[S] = List[Seq[(S, S)]]

  def take1: TakeAlias[T]

  def take2: TakeAlias[T]

  def take3: TakeAlias[T]

}
```

or extracting type alias outside (for example to companion)

```
trait Aliased[+T] {

  import Aliased.*

  def take1: TakeAlias[T]

  def take2: TakeAlias[T]

  def take3: TakeAlias[T]
}

object Aliased {
  type TakeAlias[+S] = List[Seq[(S, S)]]
  //type TakeAlias[S] = List[Seq[(S, S)]]
}
```

A quote from the spec:

https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#variance-annotations

> - The right-hand side of a type alias is always in invariant position.

> References to the type parameters in object-private or object-protected values, types, variables, or methods of the class are not checked for their variance position. In these members the type parameter may appear anywhere without restricting its legal variance annotations.

Also when you're sure that illegal usage can't lead to issues in your use case you can use `scala.annotation.unchecked.uncheckedVariance`

```
trait Aliased[+T] {

  type TakeAlias = List[Seq[(T @uncheckedVariance, T @uncheckedVariance)]]

  def take1: TakeAlias

  def take2: TakeAlias
  
  def take3: TakeAlias

}
```

or

```
trait Aliased[+T] {

  type T1 = T @uncheckedVariance
 
  type TakeAlias = List[Seq[(T1, T1)]]

  def take1: TakeAlias

  def take2: TakeAlias

  def take3: TakeAlias

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a possible solution:

```
object TrueTypeAlias {

  trait Unaliased[+T] {

    def take1: List[Seq[(T, T)]]

    def take2: List[Seq[(T, T)]]

    def take3: List[Seq[(T, T)]]
  }

  trait Aliased[+T] {

    private type TakeAlias = List[Seq[(T, T)]]

    def take1: TakeAlias

    def take2: TakeAlias

    def take3: TakeAlias
  }
}
```

Alternatively:

```
object TrueTypeAlias {

  trait Unaliased[+T] {

    def take1: List[Seq[(T, T)]]

    def take2: List[Seq[(T, T)]]

    def take3: List[Seq[(T, T)]]
  }

  trait Aliased[+T] {

    opaque type TakeAlias = List[Seq[(T, T)]]

    def take1: TakeAlias

    def take2: TakeAlias

    def take3: TakeAlias
  }

  trait Aliased2[+T] extends Aliased[T] {

    def take4: TakeAlias
  }
}
```

Comment: `private` fix doesn't work in 2.13 https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/iTBIyhmdQNmZLD1QcBJJTg

Comment: But `private[this]` works https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/iTBIyhmdQNmZLD1QcBJJTg/1 (as stated in the quote from the spec in my answer). `private[this]` is absent in Scala 3 https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/dropped-features/this-qualifier.html

Comment: Maybe variance checks were relaxed in Scala 3 even for just `private` members. I can't find a specific PR, docs, or issue. Maybe https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/7567 is relevant

Comment: @DmytroMitin Scala 3 automatically turns `private` into `private[this]` if the member is only used like `private[this]`. You can see that if you add `def foo(a: Aliased[?]): a.TakeAlias`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the new information y'all. Sorry just realised that this doesn't belong to any logic because variance is a higher-kind-ish concept. Will remove the relevant part